# Rxjs get compose like behavior

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have multiple observables that I want to chain with the concat observable. But what I need is the same behavior like compose, b needs to get the results of a and c the results of b.

```
function a(observable) {  return observable.map()... }
function b(observable) {  return observable.map()... }
function c(observable) {  return observable.map()... }

const obs = Observable.of([...])
Observable.concat(a(obs), b(obs), c(obs)).subscribe(...)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/8247/common-recipes/28035/sending-multiple-sequential-http-requests#t=201705220653540090413

Comment: Are you looking for something more complicated that `flatMap`?

Comment: Do you need the subscriber receive values emitted by all observables or just the last one one? if last one - concatMap, if all multicast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Rx does not have helper for composing function. However, is this what you was looking for?

```js
function a(source$) {
  return source$.map(x => x + '-first')
} 

function b(source$) {
  return source$.map(x => x + '-second')
} 

function c(source$) {
  return source$.map(x => x + '-third')
} 

const composed = R.compose(c, b, a);

composed(Rx.Observable.interval(1000))
  .subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.22.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can handle the error somewhere down the road e.g. in c() or somewhere before subscribe()